# TGM Updater for Wordpress - How to use exactly?

Tags: wordpress

I came across this library on GitHub which allows me to add an update functionality to a plugin that I have developed:

https://github.com/thomasgriffin/TGM-Updater

But I don't know exactly how it should work. I know another library where you just add the plugin slug to a URL, and the scripts check for the plugin-slug.zip on the other FTP server and shows in WP that an update is available and can be automatically updated.

With the TGM Updater I am asking myself if the remote url should be the plugin-slug.zip URL and this class also checks if the .zip is newer than my installed plugin version.

Does anybody know how the TGM Updater will work exactly?

Thanks.

Comment: judging by the code I think the url should point to a json file with many infos on it, like version, download link,author name and websitre, changelog, etc. there's lack of documentation, so I suggest to use this [plugin-update-checker](https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker) instead: I've already use it and it works fine, plus there is [documentation](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2010/09/02/automatic-updates-for-any-plugin/)

Comment: Yep. I already use that. Thanks.